# Number of ways to change a coin

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

I am doing this question https://leetcode.com/problems/coin-change-2/. I need to find number of ways to change a coin given the amount and denominations.

I came up with the solution to try every possibility of denominations for an amount and caching it if its already seen before.

```
class Solution(object):
    def change(self, amount, coins):
        """
        :type amount: int
        :type coins: List[int]
        :rtype: int
        """
        dp = [[-1]*len(coins)]*(amount+1)
        def changeHelper(amount, coins, index):
            if amount == 0:
                return 1

            if index<0:
                return 0

            if dp[amount][index]!=-1:
                return dp[amount][index]

            total_ways = 0
            if amount>=coins[index]:
                total_ways = changeHelper(amount-coins[index], coins, index)

            total_ways += changeHelper(amount, coins, index-1)

            dp[amount][index] = total_ways
            return dp[amount][index]


        return changeHelper(amount, coins, len(coins)-1)
```

I am getting wrong answer and have spent hours figuring out the bug.

> ```
> Test case
> 500
> [1,2,5]
> expected answer 12701
> my output 301
> ```

Comment: This code doesn't seem to be complete.  Can you post a working version?  If copy and paste, I get an 'indented error block'.  Put the inputs and a few print statements, so it is a complete piece of code.

Comment: @asylumax I have re-formatted the code

Comment: Code still isn't complete.   Put in the defaults amount and coins in variable, and show the calls.

Comment: I am not able to understand, I have specified the leetcode link, copy the code and paste it in the editor. You have default test cases written there

Comment: Yes, but that link might not work one day.  As far as I understand things, pasting the entire code makes it easier for folks to try the problem, and is usually done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine, the issue is in the `dp` list. When you do `[[-1]*len(coins)]*(amount+1)` in your example, first a list of `[-1, -1, -1]` is created then it is copied (by reference) `501` times. When you change any item in any of the lists all the other lists will get updated too which will lead to incorrect result.

To fix that, either create the list using list comprehension:

`dp = [[-1 for _ in range(len(coins))] for _ in range(amount+2)]`

or make use of the fact that `dict` lookup is `O(1)` in Python and use a `dict` for memoization to avoid such error in the future, for example:

```
dp = {}
def changeHelper(amount, coins, index):
    if amount == 0:
        return 1

    if index<0:
        return 0

    if (amount, index) in dp:
        return dp[(amount, index)]

    total_ways = 0
    if amount>=coins[index]:
        total_ways = changeHelper(amount-coins[index], coins, index)

    total_ways += changeHelper(amount, coins, index-1)

    dp[(amount, index)] = total_ways
    return dp[(amount, index)]
```

**EDIT:**

Here is more explanation to why that happened

```
>>> dp = [[-1] * 3] * 4
>>> dp
[[-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1], [-1, -1, -1]]
>>> dp[0][0] = 5
>>> dp
[[5, -1, -1], [5, -1, -1], [5, -1, -1], [5, -1, -1]]
```

Think of it like, the inner statement creates:

```
tmp = [-1, -1, -1]
```

then the outer one:

```
dp = [tmp, tmp, tmp, tmp]
```

Comment: This was really helpful, thanks a lot. Seems like I made a silly conceptual mistake on initializing lists, but I really appreciate your answer. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Here's the DP you need.

```
def change(amount, coins):
        dp = [0] * (amount + 1)
        dp[0] = 1
        for x in range(amount + 1):
            for c in coins:
                if c > x: continue
                dp[x] += dp[x - c]
        return dp[amount]
```

Comment: I want to debug my code rather than space optimizing it

Comment: you are creating a 2d array for a problem that can get solved in O(n), it is solution optimization rather than space optimization. you are overcomplicating simple stuff.

Comment: How was it reduced to 1d array in the first place? 1d space optimization was done over 2d array.

Comment: you are understanding the problem wrong. did you draw a state diagram? there is only one thing changing i.e. amount. you are running through all possibilities of amount onlyyy.

Comment: can you please help me understand the problem, maybe i need some explanation then

Comment: ok have you done bytelandian coins on codechef. it is a simpler version of this. do that first.

Comment: @AbhishekVerma the time complexity is still `O(amount * number of coins)` your code only improves space complexity as OP mentioned